# Applying a lambda function to columns on pandas avoiding redundancy

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset, which contains some NaN values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'Name':['Eve','Diana',np.NaN,'Mia','Mae',np.NaN], "Count":[10,3,np.NaN,8,5,2]})
df

    Id  Name    Count
0   1   Eve     10.0
1   2   Diana   3.0
2   3   NaN     NaN
3   4   Mia     8.0
4   5   Mae     5.0
5   6   NaN     2.0
```

I want to test if the column has a NaN value (0) or not (1) and creating two new columns. I have tried this:

```
df_clean = df
df_clean[['Name_flag','Count_flag']] = df_clean[['Name','Count']].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == np.NaN else 1, axis = 1)
```

But it mentions that `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`. I want to make it avoiding redundancy, but I see there is a mistake in my logic. Please, could you help me with this question?

The expected table is:

```
    Id  Name    Count   Name_flag  Count_flag
0   1   Eve     10.0    1          1
1   2   Diana   3.0     1          1
2   3   NaN     NaN     0          0
3   4   Mia     8.0     1          1
4   5   Mae     5.0     1          1
5   6   NaN     2.0     0          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply boolean mask by 1:

```
df[['Name_flag','Count_flag']] = df[['Name', 'Count']].isna() * 1
```

```
>>> df
   Id   Name  Count  Name_flag  Count_flag
0   1    Eve   10.0          0           0
1   2  Diana    3.0          0           0
2   3    NaN    NaN          1           1
3   4    Mia    8.0          0           0
4   5    Mae    5.0          0           0
5   6    NaN    2.0          1           0
```

For your problem of `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`

For `apply`, you cannot return a scalar 0 or 1 because you have a series as input . You have to use `applymap` instead to apply a function elementwise. But comparing to NaN is not an easy thing:

Try:

```
df[['Name','Count']].applymap(lambda x: str(x) == 'nan') * 1
```

Comment: What an elegant solution, to evaluate as a boolean is condition is met!. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Alexis. I added some explanation about your error if you want to take time to read it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `isna` and convert the boolean to int:

```
df[["Name_flag", "Count_flag"]] = df[["Name", "Count"]].isna().astype(int)
```

```
   Id   Name  Count  Name_flag  Count_flag
0   1    Eve  10.00          0           0
1   2  Diana   3.00          0           0
2   3    NaN    NaN          1           1
3   4    Mia   8.00          0           0
4   5    Mae   5.00          0           0
5   6    NaN   2.00          1           0
```

Comment: Thank you @Erfan!, I see it coerces a boolean to an int type!